# unicodedecodeerror-charmap 0x090

Tags: python, sha1

estoy haciendo un curso, el profesor utiliza python 2.7 y yo 3.9, me salta un error(dejare fotos) le pregunte al profesor y me mando a esta pagina, he estado mirando soluciones el caso es que no me salta el error pero no me descrifra la contraseña sha1.

```
import hashlib

def main():
    resolverhash = input("Hash a resolver: ")
    resolvedor = open("resolvedordeclaves.txt", 'r')

    for x in resolvedor.readlines():
        a = x.strip("\n")
        a = hashlib.sha1(a.encode('utf-8'))
        if a == resolverhash:
            print("Clave:  {}  Este Hash fue el resuelto:  {}".format(x,a.hexdigest))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ojala me puedan ayudar.

gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.
[image: Esta es la consola cuando me daba error]

[image: y esa la IDE]

ahora como la tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no pongas tu código como imágenes, pues eso obligará a quien te vaya a ayudar a copiarlo todo, reduciendo tus probabilidades de conseguir ayuda. Pega el código como texto, y ponle una línea de ``` delante y otra después para que salga correctamente formateado.

Comment: Te ayudaria, pero tipear un largo hash mirando una pequeña foto es mucho pedir de tu parte. Si quieres ayuda, facilita las cosas poniendo los textos como textos, no como fotos.

Comment: Perdonad soy nuevno y no lo sabia, voy a intentar, hacerlo para que me salte el error de antes, y lo copio. perdon una vez mas.

Comment: hola ¿que contiene resolvedordeclaves.txt?

Comment: Hola, resolvedordeclaves.txt son todos los diccionarios que nos dejo el profesor, meti dentro todas las contraseñas.

Comment: Si trabajas en windows, asegúrate que abres el fichero de texto con el _encoding_ adecuado.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Hola, puse el que puso el profesor, he probado con otros que han puesto los compañeros, y en este foro en ingle que hablaban sobre ello y decian otros encoding pero nada...no se donde esta el problema...solucione que no me saltara el error ese, pero cuando pongo para descrifrar la contraseña no hace nada...

Comment: No veo que hayas puesto ningún parámetro `encoding` en la función `open()`. Como usas windows, intenta abrir el fichero en codificación `cp1252`, que no parece que sea la que usa el fichero. Usa el `encoding` que tenga el fichero.

Comment: @ChemaCortes perdon puse mal el codigo aqui, puse el anterior, en el que estoy poniendo el encoding es este:

resolvedor = open("resolvedordeclaves.txt", encoding=('utf-8'))

soy nuevo aqui y me he liado un poco.

Comment: Vale, entonces ya está arreglado el error que pones en el título y tu problema es otro. Necesitamos que ofrezcas un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que podamos probar para ver qué es lo que te pasa.

Comment: @ChemaCortes perdon he estado fuera.
mi codigo era este:

```import hashlib
def main():
    resolverhash = input("Hash a resolver: ")
    resolvedor = open("resolvedordeclaves.txt", encoding=('utf-8'))

    for x in resolvedor.readlines():
        a = x.strip("\n")
        a = hashlib.sha1(a.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if a == resolverhash:
            print("Clave:  {}  Este Hash fue el resuelto:  {}".format(x,a.hexdigest))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```

pero @abulafia ya ha dado con la solucion, mil gracias a todos y perdon una vez mas por las foto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que, en esta línea:

```
        if a == resolverhash:
```

intentas comparar `a`, que es el resultado del hash, directamente con la cadena `resolverhash`, y esa comparación nunca puede dar `True` porque ni siquiera son variables del mismo tipo, ya que `a` es un objeto de tipo `<sha1 HASH>`, mientras que `resolverhash` es de tipo cadena.

Probablemente lo que debas comparar será el `.hexdigest()` del objeto `a`. Por tanto tu código debería ser así:

```
for x in resolvedor.readlines():
    a = x.strip("\n")
    a = hashlib.sha1(a.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()  # <--- Añadido
    if a == resolverhash:
        print("Clave:  {}  Este Hash fue el resuelto:  {}".format(x, a))
```

Comment: Hola, antes que nada gracias por tu ayuda. aunque me da error. te adjunto el error.

(venv) C:\Users\Francis\PycharmProjects\fzbr>python fzbr.py
Hash a resolver: 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francis\PycharmProjects\fzbr\fzbr.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Francis\PycharmProjects\fzbr\fzbr.py", line 11, in main
    print("Clave:  {}  Este Hash fue el resuelto:  {}".format(x,a.hexdigest))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'

Comment: es que si te fijas en mi codigo el print final imprime `a` en vez de `a.hexdigest()`, pues este ya lo habiamos extraido antes y ahora `a` es un string.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, tenias razon, no me di cuenta en lo que me acabas de comentar, perdona. Una ultima cosa, cuando descifra la contraseña en la terminal me repite lo mismo muchas veces, sabes porque puede ser? he probado pobiendo break abajo de print y asi si funcia, es correcto hacer eso? o esta mal? mil gracias. Y perdona que no ponga las cosas bien, pero estoy intentando poner el codigo y tal con las  ``` pero no se porque no se queda...

Comment: En los comentarios no funciona lo del ``` Si tienes preguntas adicionales que requieran mostrar código mejor hacías una pregunta nueva. En todo caso, si te muestra varios mensajes ha de ser porque varias líneas del fichero concuerdan con el hash buscado. Si pones `break` se abandonará el bucle tan pronto como se encuentre el primer caso que concuerde. Eso está bien si sólo te interesa ese primer caso.

Comment: seguramente entonces sea problema del fichero. Si mas que nada era para ver como descrifraba la contraseña, asi que el break va bien. Pues muchisimas gracias de verdad. Un saludo.